# Using WP Rest API to get Elementor Custom Templates

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, elementor

I use a custom template library in my WordPress Theme.
I want to know how can I setup my wordpress api to retrieve the custom templates (Elementor) data.

For example I want this URL: https://localhost/wp-json/template-manager/v1/template_id
To show my templates like this:

```
{
    "title": ".....Template title..",
    "type": ".....Template type...",
    "content": [.....Template content.....],
}
```